# Customize Algolia Autocomplete Footer Content (Magento2)

Tags: magento2, algolia

I have Algolia installed on my Magento 2 site. Which file should I edit to change the footer text in the below image?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUMju.png

Instead of saying "See products in all departments..." I'd like it to say something like "Shop All Products." Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The footer of autocomplete menu is generated in [common.js:235](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento-2/blob/334c825bc60db38ec81497269de22d2cba7ea002/view/frontend/web/internals/common.js#L235).

The extension currently doesn't offer UI way on how to customise the text. So you'd have to extend the file or modify it directly.

But be careful about updating the extension in future as it will override your changes.